# Is there no punishment for homosexual intercourse w brother

Tags: hadith-interpretation, sunni

Sahih al-Bukhari 5105
Says that u are no longer able to lawfully marry a person (I forgot who this Specific person is in relation to the sinner) but my contention is that wouldn’t that mean u wouldn’t be stoned if you’re alive for the wedding to be lawful or not.

Comment: The punishment for sodomy is disagreed upon. Also the punishment is only carried out when the act is exposed and there is evidence such as witnesses so it is possible for a person to have done the act and not gotten caught, and then repented in which case whether or not he can marry is a relevant question for himself.